# Perl: How to pull out the desired string using the starting character but needs to include them as well?

Tags: regex, perl

I have this string

```
my $word = "Chase_^%798(987%55,.#*&^*&Chase_$&^**&(()%%hjjlhh";
```

Desired output is

```
Chase_^%798(987%55,.#*&^*&
Chase_$&^**&(()%%hjjlhh
```

The string `"Chase_"` is the only clue using which I should separate them. Using split I lose the string `"Chase_"`. Then I should concatenate them. I don't have the slightest idea of how to split it but also the string `"Chase_"` should be present.`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
my $str = 'Chase_^%798(987%55,.#*&^*&Chase_$&^**&(()%%hjjlhh';
my @list = split(/(?=Chase_)/, $str);
say Dumper\@list;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'Chase_^%798(987%55,.#*&^*&',
          'Chase_$&^**&(()%%hjjlhh'
        ];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use grouping withing split's regex, you don't lose (single "o") it. Also, if you split on a string literal, not a pattern, there's no need to extract it:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $word = 'Chase_^%798(987%55,.#*&^*&Chase_$&^**&(()%%hjjlhh';

my @parts1 = split /(Chase_)/, $word;
for (my $i = 1; $i < $#parts1; $i += 2) {
    print @parts1[ $i, $i + 1 ], "\n";
}

print "--------\n";

my @parts2 = split /Chase_/, $word;
print 'Chase_', $_, "\n" for @parts2[ 1 .. $#parts2 ];
```